# Paste a string into textbox using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
String text = "test";
```

I want to paste the string text using selenium `Keys.CONTROL+"v"`. But I just couldn't find the right way to do it. Can somebody helps me of any questions in stack overflow would be very helpful.

Just to be clear I don't want to copy a text from screen like this:

```
driver.findelement(by.xpath).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"c")
```

But I want to use directly the String text to paste it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated as per requirement

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AWTException, InterruptedException {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");


    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@title='Search']"));
    String text = "test";

    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    we.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.INSERT);

    Thread.sleep(50000);
    driver.close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Shailesh, I want to use the Keys.CONTROL+"v". The reason is that the application behave diffrently when you paste a string.

Comment: Hi William, I hope updated one what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Shailesh, thanks for the update. I will implement it and accept your solution if it will work. Thank you very much

Comment: It's working Shailesh. THank you once again

Comment: Thanks William for your acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. Below code uses `JavaScriptExecutor` to pass text into a web element.

```
static WebDriver driver;
static String text = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        //Accept cookies
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Accept all']")).click();
        
        // JavaScript Executor to enter text
        JavascriptExecutor j = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        j.executeScript("document.getElementById('APjFqb').value=' " + text + "'");

        // driver.quit();
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]